# Why I got document is not defined error in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I'd like to simulate a click on a gallery (`<div class="image">`) but when I try to run this code, I got document not defined error.

```
async function gallery(page) {
 await page.waitFor(3000);
 await page.click(document.querySelector('.div image'));
}
```

What's the problem here? How can I use document.querySelector correctly with puppeteer?

Comment: There is no document in node.

Comment: But with puppeteer's browser there is, rigth? So I should be able to use document.querySelector

Comment: I have collected other elements with the code ```const partnersOnPage = await page.evaluate(() => 
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.listing__card a.listing__thumbnail'))
        .map(element => element.href.substring(element.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
      );``` so there is document in nodejs and puppeteer.

Comment: I think `document` would only be available within `page.avaluate` (according to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Try:
`async function gallery(page) {
   await page.waitFor(3000);
   await page.evaluate(() => {
       document.querySelector('div.image').click();
   })
}`

Comment: @KushagraSharma thank you, your code is working fine. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as solution.

Comment: `But with puppeteer's browser there is, rigth?`  No, there is still no document, Chromium has a document, and that's what puppeteer is controlling.  Basically you just need to call click inside the chromium instance,..  `page.evaluate` is one way, but an easier option is `page.$('div.image').click()`.  I was on mobile with my original response, so couldn't give a full response, but hoped it might have given you a hint to what was wrong.. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think document would only be available within `page.evaluate` (according to [puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) )

Try:

```
async function gallery(page) {
   await page.waitFor(3000);
   await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelector('div.image').click();
   })
}
```

Comment: How do you use it while debugging in console? It seems to be working fine, but when in debug mode with a breakout within page.eval it gives doc is not defined error

Answer (score 6):

you are calling invalid element , you can check this [document](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#q-whats-the-difference-between-a-trusted-and-untrusted-input-event)

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('div.image').click();
});
```

Comment: I still got document is not defined with ```div.image``` too.

Comment: you can check this one